# Fixing Connection Pool maxing out / Finding open connections to SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having a bit of trouble with an old website that I have inherited from someone.
It throw errors regarding a connection pool being maxed out. When it happens the website would simply then just load the HTML and nothing from the database. When it is left for a while it would then work fine, or when I would recycle the IIS application pool in Plesk.

I have done a lot of reading and research but I can't quite work it out still.
The first thing I read was to look for was any code where the database connection was not closed after it had retrieved the information. I haven't found anything like this so far.

The next thing was I found a stored procedure `sp_who2` which I was led to believe would give me the open connection but I'm a little confused as to if this is what I'm actually looking at.

When running `sp_who2` I get the below.

[image]

Is this an open connection? Or is it simply my connection that is currently looking at the database through SQL Server Management Studio?

This database is currently on a shared hosting platform so I don't have the access needed to run some of the other commands that I found.

Ideally I will move the website off a shared host, but I'd like to find out the reason for this before I do. What I'm hoping to find is where the code needs to be adjusted to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an open connection? Or is it simply my connection that is currently looking at the database through SQL Server Management Studio?

It's both. Your connection is coming from SSMS, and it is an open connection.

There are ways to get more detailed infomration than this. You can, for example, use [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), along with other DMV's like `sys.dm_exec_sessions`, and construct a query which tells you a lot of information.

But rather than write a query like that yourself, I suggest you download Adam Machanic's excellent [`sp_whoisactive`](https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive/releases). It's just a stored procedure you create, which contains a query to pull lots of useful infomration from the system metadata, with the ability to provide options to customise the output. This procedure is, I would be confident to say, the "default" procedure that everyone eventually uses for this kind of query. I might write my own more limited query against the DMV's from time to time, but most of the time, `sp_whoisactive` can give you everything you want.

One of the parameters, for example, is `@show_sleeping_spids`. This will show you connections even if they're not actually running any query. Which is sort of funny given that the procedure name is "who is *active*", but the usefulness is clear. You would want to execute this procedure like so: `exec sp_whoisactive @show_sleeping_spids = 1`, and perhaps add other paramters besides. It has powerful filtering options too, but if you don't typically have a *lot* of connections, you probably can just grab the entire output and eyeball it for relevant info.

If you can't run this because of the permissions available to you by shared hosting, then your options are severely limited. If you are only getting your own session from `sp_who2`, but you know other stuff is running, then you don't have `view server state` permission. In such cases, `sp_who2` only outputs your own session (because you are allowed to see information about your own session).